# Is there a acronym cheat sheet for linux kernel makefile?

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kbuild

I recently tried modifying the Linux kernel, but I've struggled to read the makefiles. The most confounding part to me is the abbreviations such as CC, LD, AR, NM..etc.

Despite the fact that The Linux Kernel (https://docs.kernel.org/kbuild/makefiles.html#overview) site has a thorough tutorial, I wonder if there’s any dictionary-like terminology mapping that exists.
Thanks :)

Comment: Really, it's expected that any kernel programmer could figure this out from the context.  Those aren't abbreviations, those are the names of commands.

Comment: `CC`: C Compiler, `LD`: Loader, `AR`: Archiver, `NM`: Name Manglng, and so on... `man` is what will help you a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Variables Used by Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html) is probably as close as you get.